# SEO friendly URLs Redirect Loop

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, modx

I'm trying to set up SEO friendly URLs for MODX Revolution but I'm having trouble with a redirect loop. I'm working on the site in Bluehost. The domain name of the site hasn't transferred yet as I'm working on migrating the site to MODX so I'm using the shared IP.

```
# Friendly URLs Part
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
# Force all pages to go to www.domain.com for SEO
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^12.123.123.123/~username/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://12.123.123.123/~username/$1 [R=301,L]
# Friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
# Additional Settings Follow
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
BrowserMatch "MSIE" brokenvary=1
BrowserMatch "Mozilla/4.[0-9]{2}" brokenvary=1
BrowserMatch "Opera" !brokenvary
SetEnvIf brokenvary 1 force-no-vary
```

When I visit a page, the URL appears to be formatted correctly:

```
http://12.123.123.123/~username/about.html
```

but I get a redirect loop every time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your second `RewriteCond` makes no sense, because `12.123.123.123/~username/` is not a host name.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you were trying to achieve, but I would restore the default .htaccess file for MODX Revolution (https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/blob/develop/ht.access) and adjust it as follows...

As your site is currently in a subfolder, set it using `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~username
```

Restore the default "non-www to www" rewrite conditions, you won't need them until your site is accessible using a domain name (rather than IP address):

```
# Force all pages to go to www.domain.com for SEO
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example-domain-please-change\.com [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example-domain-please-change.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Leave the rest as it is.